# Create classes with stored then, then call function if it exists using input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is what I'm trying to do:
1. Make a number of class instances from a class template. 2. Store a function in each class. 3. Check the user input to see if it matches one of the classes. 4. Use the associated function.

I'm basically a beginner so please bear with me/use simple english, sorry. Anyway, I've tried just about anything I can think of and have been googling for hours. I want the user to be able to input text and then if that text matches a class instance, call the associated function IN that instance (or other class attribute).

```
# --------------------------------------------
# ------List of available functions-----------
#---------------------------------------------
def myfunc_a(a):
    a = print("First action.")
def myfunc_b(a):
    a = print("Second action.")
#--------------------------------------------
#-------- Class constructor------------------
#--------------------------------------------
class UserSelect(object):
    count = 0 
    def __init__(self, title, desc, usable, action):
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
        self.perm = False
        self.action = myfunc_a
        UserSelect.count += 1

    def describe(self):
        t = ("Default Title")
        d = ("Default description.")
        print ("\n%s \n%s" % (t, d))

    def actions(self, data):
        return task(self.action, data)
#---------------------------------------------
# ------- Available instances ----------------
#---------------------------------------------
option_a = UserSelect("Option A", "This is option A.", True, myfunc_a)
option_b = UserSelect("Option B", "This is option B.", True, myfunc_b)
#---------------------------------------------
#-------- Get user input and match it---------
#---------------------------------------------
userin = input("What would you like to do? ")

while True:
    userin = input("What would you like to do? ")
    if isinstance(userin, UserSelect): #------check if input exists first
        print("Doing task.") #---Checking if it's actually found, delete later
         #---Call related function... 
    else:
        print("Unrecognized command.\n")
```

So if they type "option_a", I want it to check if there is a class instance called option_a, the look in that instance to execute its associated function (myfunc_a).

I have no clue how to do the last part. This is where I'm currently at, but I'm getting the error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'actions'". I know I'm probably doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `input`, the `userin` is only a string, you can put the created objects into a dictionary

```
created_objects = {'option_a': option_a, 'option_b': option_b}
```

Then, use a `try except` block like

```
userin = input("What would you like to do? ")
try:
    user_obj = created_objects[userin]
    print("Doing task.")
    # the task 

except KeyError:
    print("Unrecognized command.\n")
```

**Reformated code**

This is a reformated version of your code, you can understand more about python class from this

```
def myfunc_a(name):
    print("action %s." % name)
def myfunc_b(name):
    print("action %s." % name)

class UserSelect():
    count = 0 

    def __init__(self, title, desc, usable, action):
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
        self.perm = False
        self.action = action

        # I don't really understand what you are trying to do here 
        # UserSelect.count += 1

    def describe(self):
        print ("\n%s \n%s" % (self.title, self.desc))

    def actions(self, data):
        self.action(data)


option_a = UserSelect("Option A", "This is option A.", True, myfunc_a)
option_b = UserSelect("Option B", "This is option B.", True, myfunc_b)
created_objects = {'option_a': option_a, 'option_b': option_b}

userin = input("What would you like to do? ")
try:
    user_obj = created_objects[userin]
    print("Doing task.")
    user_obj.actions('a')

except KeyError:
    print("Unrecognized command.\n")
```

Comment: That actually makes the most sense to me so far, but how to I get it to do the actual task? I tried using options[userin].invoke(), but it only ever seems to use the default task in the class structure. Not the ones assigned to the instances.

Comment: @Literally Mom I have added a reformated version of your code,  I think it is enough to address your confusions.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed! I spent HOURS trying to figure it out myself because I wanted to understand rather than just have someone give me the code, so thank you. I do a lot more from here I think!

Comment: @Literally Mom You’re welcome! :) I’m glad my answer helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your instances of the class in separate variables, store them as values in a dictionary:

```
options = {
    "option_a": UserSelect("Option A", "This is option A.", True, myfunc_a),
    "option_b": UserSelect("Option B", "This is option B.", True, myfunc_b)
}
```

And ensure that one of the methods provided by the class will actually call the stored function:

```
class UserSelect:
    # other stuff...
    def invoke(self):
        # add whatever logic is needed to determine the parameters for the call...
        self.action()
```

And then use the user's string input as a key for the dictionary, get the corresponding instance and call the method:

```
userin = input("What would you like to do? ")
options[userin].invoke()
```

Comment: That explains/helps a lot! I was checking out dictionaries at first, but couldn't figure out how to link them to the function. I didn't realize you could just drop the actual function in there without the () and it would work. Thank you. One more question if I may; how exactly do I properly check if the instance DOES exist? I tried "if isinstance(userin, UserSelect):" but it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Okay I got it working, but it seems to only use the default action associated with UserSelect (option-a) and I can't get it to call the actual instance options (like option_b).

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question in that case and show what you're trying now. Try to make a *minimal* example that shows the problem; cut out features like the `describe` method etc.

Comment: @LiterallyMom so, an important concept to grok: functions in Python are "first-class objects", that means that if you `def func(): ...` then `func` is *just a function object*, like a `list` or a `str`, and you can pass it to another function or return it from a function, put it in a list, or a dict etc. Not all programming languages have first-class objects, but Python does, which makes this sort of thing easy.